# log4j2 TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy isn't logging anything

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I'm looking to create a simple `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` that creates a new log file every 5 min. But it's not logging anything. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here are the details, thank you!

My log4j dependencies:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>


log4j.rootLogger=INFO,rolling

log4j.appender.rolling.type=RollingFile
log4j.appender.rolling.name=fileAppender
log4j.appender.rolling.fileName=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/spark-${date:yyyyMMdd_HH-mm}.log
log4j.appender.rolling.filePattern=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/spark-%d{yyyyMMdd_HH-mm}-%i.log
log4j.appender.rolling.layout.type=PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rolling.layout.pattern=%d %p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.rolling.policies.type=Policies
log4j.appender.rolling.policies.time.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.rolling.policies.time.interval=5
log4j.appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate=true

log4j.rootLogger.level=info
log4j.rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref=fileLogger
```

Error Log:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.rolling
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "rolling".
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/mnt1/yarn/usercache/hadoop/filecache/45/__spark_libs__6130489434181934811.zip/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

**Final Working Result (creates log every minute, and rotates monthly):**

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, loggerId
log4j.appender.loggerId=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/spark.log
log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/spark_%d{dd-HHmm}.log.gz
log4j.appender.loggerId.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.loggerId.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.loggerId.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This creates log every minute, we can't do 5 minute increments unless we use xml or customization.

This rotates monthly, I took out the `yyyyMM` so it can rotate monthly, take out `dd` and it'll rotate daily:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, loggerId
log4j.appender.loggerId=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/spark.log
log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/spark_%d{dd-HHmm}.log.gz
log4j.appender.loggerId.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.loggerId.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.appender.loggerId.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your configuration (run with `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to catch them all):

- Log4j2 does not have properties prefixed with `log4j.`, remove the prefix,
- There is no property `spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir` in your configuration. If you meant to use a Java system property use `${sys:spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}`,
- You define the root logger twice:

  - once with the shorthand notation introduced in version 2.17.2: `rootLogger = INFO, rolling`,
  - another time using the full notation:

    ```
    rootLogger.level = INFO
    rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling ref = fileLogger
    ```

  neither definition uses the name you gave to the appender: **`fileAppender`**.
- You don't have a `<SizeBasedRollingPolicy>`, but your pattern contains `%i`. If you remove `-%i`, your `fileName` and `filePattern` are identical: you probably want to use a [direct rollover strategy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#DirectWrite_Rollover_Strategy) instead and omit `fileName`.

Comment: Thank you, in the interest of keeping it simple, I'll try without `%i` first and see if it works. Will definitely put the debug tip to use.

Comment: Simplicity is not the only reason to use a `DirectRolloverStrategy`: the rolling appender does not check if the name of the "current" log file is different from the name of the "archived" log file. If this happens, the `DefaultRolloverStrategy` will simply fail to rename the current file to itself.

Comment: Got it, I've provided the `final result` in the original post to confirm and in case future visitors need the answer.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the error, looks like it's looking for `log4j` perhaps I'm still on log4j 1.x for some reason?

Comment: @sojim2: you named your appender `fileAppender`, so you should use `rootLogger = INFO, fileAppender`.

Comment: I've updated the `final result` to latest. But it looks like it's only outputting in `stderr` file. I'm actually looking to have INFO logs in spark.log, and every 5 minutes, it should created a timestamped gz file. The `debug` doesn't seem to be outputting any debug message either. At the beginning of the `stderr` it shows this `Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties`